# Deploy a package(wsp file) with dependent assemblies to GAC but dont remove them on Retracting, how?

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, gac

When developing a SharePoint solution(a webpart for instance) sometimes we need to add some required assemblies(a telerik assembly for instance) to GAC.

So for that we will add this assemblies via Visual Studio in Advanced section of Package.
Ok so far so good, when we Package the project, Visual studio or wspbuilder will generate a wsp file which our assemblies is exist in the wsp file and it will deploy the assemblies  to GAC.

The question is this: when wsp file retract or remove from the farm, those required assemblies will be remove from GAC too and if those assemblies were needed by some other Solutions then those solutions will be stop working.

I just want to Add or Overwrite those assemblies to GAC when deploying the wsp and not removing it from GAC when retracting, is this possible in anyway?

Comment: Did you try using a Module, then create the wsp? The solution retract then will not remove the files provisioned using a module. Can you check this.?

Comment: No I'll be glad to know how, step by step please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a different WSP with those dependent assemblies. You can version and deploy this WSP independently. Just be sure to not GAC deploy these assemblies from your solution WSP.

Comment: So you mean i create a New SharePoint project via Visual Studio and just add those assemblies to the Package. Then deploy it and never retract or remove it, right?

Comment: I concur with the above answer.

Comment: @JalaliShakib yes, create a new SharePoint project and add that assembly to the package.